# Unity3D vertical / horizontal fog/

Tags: unity-game-engine, distance, visible, light

I found something like that [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/943820/any-way-to-adjust-verticalhorizontal-fog-densitys.html) on the internet, but nobody helped and that question is from april. So I ask one more time. I have really high windmills ( above 150 meters) in my game and I want they would be visible although fog is very dense (it wroks that way in real life).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe nobody answered before because it is very well documented on unity's manual.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-GlobalFog.html

If adjusting this distance/height attributes from global fog doesn't fit your needs then you can find some third-party fog system on unity store, but what you described in your question is apparently possible with genuine fog system.

Comment: Thank you very much. Only fog I've known had been lighing fog.

Comment: You're welcome. Always search in documentation first. Unity covers very well their APIs and probably you will find your answer there with examples.